# Any XML/XSD Tutorials For The Novice?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, extensible

Does anyone know of any tutorials about XSD/XML for the novice, that explains things simply but goes into great detail on how to do things?

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp

Comment: I was told not to use them, to many mistakes in their "tutorials".  See: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 5):

Here's a tutorial about validating XML using XSDs: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-valid/index.html

EDIT - here's a tutorial that may be more suited to the novice: http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=43

Comment: That's not what I asked for, so it's useless to me at this point in time.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Too advanced?  Assumes too much prior knowledge?   If you can explain what you're looking to work on, then I can maybe find a better tutorial.

Comment: Guess you didn't read my question, or you would've seen the following word: novice....

Comment: I read your question and judged (evidently incorrectly) that the IBM tutorial was pitched at an appropriate level for an XML novice (on the basis that they had prior programming experience); and that it explained things whilst also going "into great detail on how to do things"  The alternative is likely to be w3schools type tutorials which may oversimplify, but I'll see what I can find

Answer (score 0):

The XSD standard includes a "primer", which explains each XSD element, and shows an example of how to use them: [XML Schema Part 0: Primer Second Edition - W3C Recommendation 28 October 2004](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/)